# how to turn my activity to dialog

Tags: android

how do I make current activity to dialog ? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in advance.
ICS and above.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TabListener {

      final String[] page_titles = new String[]{"Home", "contact", "Apps"};
        //this will go the description TextView
            final String[] desc = new String[]{
                "This is the homepage ",
                "contact",
                "apps"
        };
    ViewPager pager;

    ActionBar bar;

    Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





           pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

          bar = getActionBar();

            myAdaptertest1 mAdapter = new myAdaptertest1(this);

            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

            pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                    bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });



            Tab hometab = bar.newTab();
            hometab.setText("Home");
            hometab.setTabListener(this);
            bar.addTab(hometab);

            Tab cameratab = bar.newTab();
            cameratab.setText("contact");
            cameratab.setTabListener(this);
            bar.addTab(cameratab);

            Tab exploretab = bar.newTab();
            exploretab.setText("apps");
            exploretab.setTabListener(this);
            bar.addTab(exploretab);


            bar.show();
            bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 
            bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);



    }


    private class myAdaptertest1 extends PagerAdapter{

        Context context;

        public myAdaptertest1(Context c){
            this.context = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return page_titles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return v.equals(o);
        }





        public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null, false);

            TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            TextView description = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);

            title.setText(page_titles[position]);
            description.setText(desc[position]);

            //This is very important
            ( (ViewPager) pager ).addView( vi, 0 );

            return vi;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View pager, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((View) view);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Activity and you can make it dialog-like. If you are working for devices prior to 4.0 you will have to do the following:

Create a folder res/values-v11 (this will work for API 11+) and after doing so, add a file called `styles.xml`. In this file type the following:

```
<resources>
    <style name="my_activity_theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
</resources>
```

Then in your styles.xml located in your in /res/values folder add this lines:

```
<resources>
    <style name="my_activity_theme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
</resources>
```

and then, apply it to your application in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    ...
    <android:theme="@style/my_activity_theme"/>

</activity
```

This way you will be able to have a floating activity. I haven't tested it but I think it is worth trying.

Hope it is what you are looking for

Comment: tried `<style name="PopupTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>` :::::::: getting error ::::::::::::::
         `bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

Comment: Also tried your code but its not dialog .I need to popup the above code in dialog .How do I do that?